# static page accept a object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

hi im working in a resevation application and im new in ruby on rails developement im just wondering if it is posible that a static page accepts paramater or object comming form another page like wise
routing from reservation with a route of
`<%= link_to "add functionrooms", reservation_page_functionroom_path(@reservation) %>`

while the controller page with functionroom action

```
 def functionroom
    @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:reservation_id])
    @function_room = FunctionRoom.all 
  end
```

my route is

```
 resources :reservations do
   resources :reservation_function_rooms
   resources :reservation_packages
   get 'pages/functionroom'
   resources :package_line_items
  end
```

thank you in advance if its not possilbe i really need an advice im trying to add a functionroom to a reservation just like an addto cart process im currently trying to use a static page where functionrooms are listed and a "add to reservation" on it thanks in advance

Comment: Is this really a static page? like it exists in public/pages/functionroom.html? Or is pages a controller with an action of functionroom?

Comment: not really a static page its a simi static it has controller page with an action functionroom in it thanks

Comment: Ok, so: yes it can. just set in the controller. If you have trouble, please add here and I'll go into more details in an answer.

Comment: i already add the page controller with functionroom action on it but it still gave me the error i wonder if my routing is right?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want this as

```
resources :reservation do
  get "functionroom", controller: "pages"
end
```

Then in your PagesController,

```
def functionroom
  @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:reservaton_id])
  # set whatever else here
end
```